# How to encode JSON object from an array in php?

Tags: php, javascript, json

My code looks like:

```
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $j = 1; 
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();

        $bcData[] = array(
           'title'=>get_the_title(),
        );

$j++;
    }
echo json_encode($bcData);
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```

`$bcData` array outputs(using `print_r` ):

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [title] => Pink Nail Shop 9 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [title] => Pink Nail Shop 8 ) 
)
```

When I encode this array to json (using `json_encode`), the newly created json looks like:

```
[{"title":"Pink Nail Shop 9"},{"title":"Pink Nail Shop 8"}]
```

While I need json like this:

```
[{"shop":{"title":"Pink Nail Shop 9"}},{"shop":{"title":"Pink Nail Shop 8"}}]
```

Hopefully this makes sense, as I've tried hard to articulate what I am trying to accomplish.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to nest your appended arrays then in another one with `"shop"=>` as key.

Comment: Why would you expect that output if your PHP data structure doesn't match?

Comment: I need to use it with some JavaScript plugin where I need same structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if ( $query->have_posts() )
{
    $bcData = array();
    $j = 1; 
    while ( $query->have_posts() )
    {
        $query->the_post();

        $bcData[] = array(
            'shop' => array(
                'title'=>get_the_title()
            )
        );
        $j++;
    }
    echo json_encode($bcData);
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```

Comment: It outputs only: [{"shop":{"title":"Pink Nail Shop 9"}}] its inside a loop.

Comment: btw answer from miguelcaires is correct and it works like I want.

Comment: @Imran are you testing my code ? my code result is : `[{"shop":{"title":"Test 0"}},{"shop":{"title":"Test 1"}},{"shop":{"title":"Test 2"}}]` your problem is another

Comment: @Imran You're welcome, if your problem exist yet, edit your question, and add complete your source code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34108/discussion-between-imran-and-d-a-v-o-o-d)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$bcData['shop'][] = array(
   'title'=>get_the_title(),
);
echo json_encode($bcData);
```

Comment: And have you? The index "shop" is at the wrong spot in your code.